# Android in-app purchase failed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in-app billing system in my application, but I cannot query the inventory to retrieve the subscriptions, because I'm getting the following error:

```
IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)
```

What have I done:

1. Signed APK is uploaded in Google Play's Store in closed ALPHA and it's
   published
2. I have added the tester account (gmail) in the testers section (the
   same gmail account is used on the testing device)
3. I have sent an e-mail with a link to the testers e-mail to "become a
   tester" for the application (I also see the application in the Play
   Store if I search for it)
4. I have created the subscriptions and all are published
5. The application was reviewed by Google and all seems to be fine
   (status: published)
6. The application version name "1.1.5-alpha-15", version code "15" and package name is the same as on Google Play's store

The code (in activity):

```
private IabHelper mIabHelper;    

// Init setup listener
private IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener mIabSetupListener = new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
      if (result.isSuccess()) {
         // Load success, now query for inventory
         List<String> skus = new ArrayList();
         skus.add("packagename.org.dev.subscription.monthly");
         skus.add("packagename.org.dev.subscription.yearly");

         mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skus, mQueryInventoryFinishedListener);
      }
   }
};

// Listener to load the subscriptions
private IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryInventoryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
      if (result.isFailure()) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Failure, check error!");
         return;
      }
   }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
   super.onCreate(savedState);

   mIabHelper = new IabHelper(this, PUBLIC_KEY_BASE_64);
   mIabHelper.enableDebugLogging(true, "BILLING");
   mIabHelper.startSetup(mIabSetupListener);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (mIabHelper == null || !mIabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mIabHelper != null) {
        mIabHelper.dispose();
    }
}
```

I copied the same APK on the device (signed) and installed it, but I'm getting the above error. I also run the application in debug mode, same error. I don't know what to do.

I have seen here (stackoverflow) that Google APIs is caching some data. Should I do a factory reset? Or how can I clear the cached data?

Comment: Is your `license key` correct? which billing API are you using?

Comment: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'

Comment: i meant from https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Signature verification fails mostly if the base 64 public key for your app is not correct. make sure you are using correct "PUBLIC_KEY_BASE_64".